# Ruby class method behaviour

Tags: ruby

Consider below chunk of code:

```
class A
  def self.a(b)
    if b > 0
      b * b
    end
  end
end
```

Now calling method a as below:

```
2.3.0 :015 > A.a(2)
 => 4 
2.3.0 :016 > A.a(0)
 => nil
```

Why nil on passing 0 as argument?

Comment: because 0 isn't greater than 0, that's why it's returning `nil`

Comment: Remember, all Ruby methods return a value. `if xxx end` is the same as `if xxx else nil end`.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your method if you want to return anything else but nil as @cary-swoveland mentioned like:

```
class A
  def self.a(b)
    if b > 0
      b * b
    else
      puts 'Calculation not possible'
      # or whatever you want your method to return
    end
 end
end
```

Additionally, you can modify your conditional to `if b >=0` if you want it to work for zero

Answer (score 0):

All ruby methods return `last` statement/expression by default, if there is no return mentioned previously. So, in your case,

```
A.a(0) #Last statement executed end, as 0 > 0 is false, without going in if. SO, it returns nothing, in other words null/nil.
```

As specified by @dstrants, you can add `else` to see some output or you can do as follows (no need of `else` clause),

```
class A
  def self.a(b)
    if b > 0
      return b * b
    end
    return "Value <= 0"
  end
end
```

This will result in output other than `nil`.

**p.s.** Don't use static methods(`self` methods), until you absolutely want to!